# Kill only a specific Command Prompt Process Remotely with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, get-wmiobject

I am trying to write a script to remote kill a specific command prompt process.
If I locally run get-process I can see that the CMD.exe process can be narrowed down by what is set in the field "MainWindowTitle"

If I get use Get-Process -computer name or get CIMInstance  the field "MainTitleWindow" comes back as blank.

```
$ses = New-CimSession -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred
$process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_process -CimSession $ses -filter "name = 'cmd.exe'"
$process | Select-Object name,MainWindowTitle
Remove-CimSession -CimSession $ses


name    MainWindowTitle
----    ---------------
cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from **MSDN**:

> A process has a main window associated with it only if the process has
>   a graphical interface. If the associated process does not have a main
>   window (so that MainWindowHandle is zero), MainWindowTitle is an empty
>   string ("").

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_MainWindowTitle).

I tried to compare with other processes but the result is the same...

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the output of the `tasklist` command. Like this:

```
$cmds = tasklist /v |
    Where-Object {$_ -like "cmd.exe*"} |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop @{"ID"=[int]$_.Substring(30,5); `
                                              "Title"=$_.Substring(157)}
    }

$cmds
```

[image]

Comment: How would one do this for a remote PC.

Comment: It should work with S argument: `tasklist /v /s COMPUTER`, but I'm not able to test right now.

Comment: Sadly the window title doesn't get returned from a remote session (I tried /s COMPUTERNAME)

Answer (score 0):

$Process = Get-CimInstance CIM_Process -CimSession $Ses | Where-Object{ $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name }

using this you can also get the ProcessID and ParentProcessID. 
you can then use the similar commands to then find the CMD process that uses the ParentProcessID of your main script. 
You must close both the main process of the script and the command prompt as well or else the script will keep running.

Comment: Tried this but couldn't see the window title locally or remotely